# How do I update an Integervalue in a .plist?

Tags: iphone, database, cocos2d-iphone, plist

I want to update an Integer Value inside my "Secret.plist".
Here*s a picture: http://img214.imageshack.us/img214/8005/bildschirmfoto20101114u.png

Now, in my application, I want the gold value to change, here is my code so far:

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Secret" ofType:@"plist"];
NSMutableDictionary *tempDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];

NSNumber *goldNumber = [NSNumber numberWithInt:1234];
[tempDict setObject:goldNumber forKey:@"Gold"];
[tempDict writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
```

My .plist didn't update after I executed the application, there still is a "5000" and not a "1234". What Am I doing wrong?

EDIT: My new value inside my .plist isn't saved/updated after I quit the application. As long as the applications runs, the values are somehow updated. So when I retrieve the value AFTER I updated it, it's correct. When I restart my application, it isn't updated anymore.    NSMutableDictionary *tempDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];

```
    [tempDict setObject:@"A new String." forKey:@"key"];
    [tempDict writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
```

Not even this one would work for me. Does anybody has the code that simply would, will save my data to my .plist so that I can retrieve it when I restart my app?

Comment: There's more going on here than is shown by the code sample. When I tried it, the sample updated the stored plist when run in the iPhone simulator. What version of iOS are you running it on? Are you running it on a real device or the simulator? Would you post a [more complete sample](http://sscce.org/)?

Answer (score 0):

Is this Secret.plist located in the app bundle? If you want to edit a file you should copy it outside the app bundle. There are standard directories where you can put stuff.

```
NSArray *documentPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDir = [documentPaths objectAtIndex:0];
```

The `documentsDir` is one place you could put it.

Except for that the code looks fine.

Comment: It's in my resources folder. Where should I copy it to? Doesn't it work if I keep it inside of my resources folder?

Comment: Your resources folder (or its content) will end up in your app bundle directory. Changing stuff inside your app bundle will mess up code signing. Instead, on first launch, copy the Secret.plist to the documentsDir I specified above and try modifying that file instead.

Comment: I don't know what you mean. I added the lines above on top of the other code snippet, but that can't be right somehow. NSArray *documentPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
  NSString *documentsDir = [documentPaths objectAtIndex:0];
  
  NSMutableDictionary *tempDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:documentsDir];
  
  NSNumber *goldNumber = [NSNumber numberWithInt:1234];
  [tempDict setObject:goldNumber forKey:@"Gold"];
  [tempDict writeToFile:documentsDir atomically:YES];

Comment: `NSApplicationSupportDirectory` seems more appropriate than `NSDocumentDirectory`, though you'll want to create & use a subdirectory of it for a storage location. As for signing, you can always [exclude plists from the seal](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#technotes/tn2007/tn2206.html%23TNTAG14).

Comment: Before I go about such complicated tasks, I simply want my value inside of my .plist to be changed. Do I really have to do all these steps in order to work with a simple .plist?

Comment: The doc on excluding files from the seal doesn't apply to iPhone apps, so is of little use here. On the iPhone, you have to set the "Code Signing Resource Rules Path" build option for the app (select the app in the Targets section of the Groups and Files pane, then press ⌘-I, then go to the Build tab). However, the format for the resource rules plist should be the same as outlined in the OS X code signing doc. Furthermore, an `NSApplicationSupportDirectory` may not exist on an iPhone.